# Python Pandas pivot_table : unexpected results

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

Let's take following pandas data frame :

`df = pandas.DataFrame({'date':[13,13,13,13],'city':['NY','NY','SF','SF'],'timeOfTheDay':['day','night','day','night'],'count':[2,3,4,5]})`

Let me illustrate this :

```
     date city timeOfTheDay  count
0    13   NY        day        2
1    13   SF        night      3
2    13   NY        day        4
3    13   SF        night      5
```

I've been trying both following methods :

```
pivot1 = pd.pivot_table(df,index=['date','city'],columns=['timeOfTheDay'],values=['count'])
pivot2 = df.pivot_table('count',['date','city'],'timeOfTheDay')
```

Expected result :

```
           day  night
 date city            
 13   NY      2      3
      SF      4      5
```

What I get instead (in both cases) :

```
timeOfTheDay  day  night
date city               
13   NY       3.0    NaN
     SF       NaN    4.0
```

Do you get same results ?
Any idea how I should change my command to get expected pivot_table result ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me working your solution without `[]` for avoid `MutliIndex`:

```
pivot1 = pd.pivot_table(df,index=['date','city'],columns='timeOfTheDay',values='count')
print (pivot1)
timeOfTheDay  day  night
date city               
13   NY         2      3
     SF         4      5
```

Comment: Thanks Jezrael. Just tested your suggestion but still got the same result with the NaN popping in and wrong numbers (3.0 and 4.0)...

Comment: @JCDB - Problem is with data in question? Or with real data?

Comment: With data in question (the simple 4x4 sample above)

Comment: @JCDB - It is weird, what is your pandas version?

Comment: Tested in two environments in which print(pd.__version__) returns either 1.1.5 or 1.2.1

Comment: Solution is good I had a problem in my test dataframe explaining previous comments